# Why is $z^2$ a conformal mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

It's not a one-to-one mapping, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

$e^z$ is one-to-one, when restricted to a horizontal strip of width = $2\pi i$.

Is it a similar argument for $z^2$?

Thanks,

Edit: $z^2$ doubles angles (and squares magnitudes of numbers in complex exponential form.), so it seems one-to-one - I guess I am possibly confusing myself with the conformal mapping $z^2$ with the polynomial equation, $z^2$ + az = 0.

Comment: Since $2\theta$ and $2(\theta+\pi)$ differ by $2\pi$, they represent the same ray in the complex plane, thus $z\mapsto z^2$ is not injective.

Comment: Since the derivative of $z\mapsto z^2$ is $2z$, away from $z=0$, the derivative of $z\mapsto z^2$ is not $0$ and so it is conformal (it locally preserves angles, not necessarily globally).

Comment: got it @robjohn.  thanks, as usual.  I just notice that on Wikipedia, there are strangely two definitions of conformal mappings - the first is the usual: conformal maps on a region U are analytic functions on U with non-zero derivative everywhere.  Then a second definition says that a map is conformal if it is one-to-one and holomorphic.  Wiki then warns that the two definitions are not the same thing...

Comment: and my concern was that $z^2$ is of course not one-to-one ... but I'm guessing that the one-to-one condition (along with analyticity) is sufficient but not necessary in defining conformal maps, @robjohn?

Comment: Conformal maps definitely don't have to be one-one. I've added an attempt at an intuitive geometrical explanation to my answer below.

Comment: Locally conformal means it is conformal on a small neighborhood. On a small neighborhood, $z^2$ can be defined injectively.

Comment: I recall that we had spoken about this recently - and for me to not confuse global properties (injectivity) with local properties (analyticity) of a complex function.  I'll go back and review that now...thanks @robjohn...I think one-to-one + analyticity implies conformality, but the implication is only one-sided...

Comment: ah, that's right, @robjohn - right back to the basics of Calc I.  thanks!

Comment: ok, got it - thanks @RobArthan!

Comment: So a function $f(z) = z^2$ is conformal of both kinds for all $z$ or for $|z| \le 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is conformal on $\mathbb{C} \mathop{\backslash} \{0\}$. At $0$ the derivative is $0$ and it is not conformal (as you say, it doubles angles subtended at $0$).

My mental model of $z \mapsto z^2$ is two turns of a spiral staircase projected onto the ground floor: that mapping is two-to-one but preserves (plan view) angles except at the centre of the staircase.

Comment: Thanks, @RobArthan.  So, the fact that $z^2$ is not one-to-one does not rule it out as a conformal map, using the usual definition that you've brought up.  But, as I commented to RobJohn (see above) ...there is another definition on Wikipedia that says "a map is conformal if it is one-to-one and analytic."

Comment: If that is a *definition*, then, I believe it should be *if and only if*, so that ...z^2 needs to be one-to-one to satisfy this requirement...

Comment: so perhaps: conformality if and only if analyticity and non-zero derivative, but the second "definition" is:  one-to-one + analyticity implies conformality, but *not* necessarily the converse...

Comment: which concerns me, since I believe we always treat definitions as if and only if statements...

Comment: very nice edit, @robarthan :-).  in that case, I will move on to a new problem to solve!  thanks again...

Comment: The wikipedia evidence for the definition requiring conformal mappings to be one-one is a link to some course notes. Perhaps the author of these notes was thinking of Riemann surfaces (where the singularities have been resolved).

Comment: Hi @robarthan - can I ask you one more question regarding this post?  *if* the mapping is said to be one-to-one and conformal, say, on the upper half plane, then the function cannot possibly be anything else other than a linear polynomial (or in full generality, a linear fractional transformation.)  Is my thinking correct?  We can rule out higher degree polynomials (by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), as well as all of the transcendental functions, which are all periodic, hence not one-to-one...

Comment: @RobArthan What do you mean by "angles subtended at $0$"? I understand that $z^2=r^2e^{i2\theta}$, but not sure by what you mean when you say subtended at $0$. It seems the function always doubles angles.

Comment: @AlJebr: see what $z \mapsto z^2$ does to $\angle uvw$ (the angle subtended by $u$ and $w$ at $v$) when $u = 1 +\epsilon  i$, $v = 1$ and $w = 1 + \epsilon$ as the positive real $\epsilon$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$z^2$ is a conformal mapping because it is complex differentiable and it's derivative is non-zero everywhere except at $0$ (where it is not conformal).

You can see why analytic functions are conformal as follows.  Let $z_0$ be a point where $f$ is analytic with non-zero derivative.  Then for two points $z_i$ close to $z_0$ we have by Taylor that
$$f(z_i) \approx f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z_i - z_0)$$
This mapping is conformal if the angle between the vector $z_1 - z_0$ and $z_2 - z_0$ is preserved.  Using the above then
$$\frac{f(z_2) - f(z_0)}{f(z_1) - f(z_0)} \approx \frac{f'(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}\frac{z_2 - z_0}{z_1 - z_0}$$
In general, the ratio of two complex numbers $w_2$ and $w_1$ is given by
$$\frac{w_2}{w_1} = \frac{r_2}{r_1}e^{i(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}$$
where $r_i, \phi_i$ are the polar coordinates of $w_i$. From this we see that the angles are preserved through the mapping.

Comment: Thanks so much, @mauddib!! :-)